# Mobile Web App Java Script alert

Tags: javascript, mobile-application

I am working on a mobile web app using javascript

I am wondering what is the best way to notify my users of an error

For example, upon entering a wrong password, I want to notify them that the password is incorrect.

I tried using:

```
alert('You entered a wrong password');
```

but on the mobile phone, when running the app it does not work to well

Any suggestions on how to notify and alert my users upon using the app?

Comment: Are you targeting a particular mobile device? Or are you targeting all of them? What do you mean by `alert()` doesn't work well? Did it not show and/or did it behave in a way you didn't like?

Comment: for iphone. alert() does not behave like i'd like it to

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your UI and what you want more than anything.  You could just update the DOM to output some kind of error flag next to a field, place a warning image, put borders, modal information boxes, all sorts to be honest.